# Fraction adding java program not working right

Tags: java, fractions

Having trouble with this final program for my Java class. We have to only use concepts we have learned so far so I cannot use other classes. Basically just loops and arrays and methods.

So for this program we have to add any five sets of fractions entered and give the GCD and the results in the lowest form. I have to show all data in the first table and then a second table with the original data and the GCD and the results in the lowest form. It has to be tested with this data:

```
1/4 + 1/2
2/3 + 1/3
7/8 + 1/8
2/9 + 4/27
7/25 + 2/5
```

Here is the code I have so far. (Be gentle, I'm still new at this)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int[] num1Array = new int[5];
        int[] num2Array = new int[5];
        int[] deno1Array = new int[5];
        int[] deno2Array = new int[5];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int x=0;x<5;x++) {                                    //Get all data from user
            System.out.println("Enter data for problem " + (x+1));
            System.out.println("Enter numberator for fraction 1");
            num1Array[x] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter denominator for fraction 1");
            deno1Array[x] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter numberator for fraction 2");
            num2Array[x] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter denominator for fraction 2");
            deno2Array[x] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("********************");
        }
        System.out.println("*****ORIGINIAL DATA ******");  //Output all entered data
        System.out.println("First Fraction \t Second Fraction");
        for(int y=0;y<5;y++) {
            System.out.printf("%1d/%1d   \t\t %1d/%1d\n", num1Array[y], deno1Array[y], num2Array[y], deno2Array[y]);
        }
        System.out.println("*******FRACTIONS SHOWING ADDED RESULTS*********"); //Display results
        System.out.println("First Fraction \t Second Fraction GCD     Results");
        for(int z=0;z<5;z++){

            int finalgcd = gcdfinal(num1Array[z], num2Array[z], deno1Array[z], deno2Array[z]);
            int addFrac = fracAdd(num1Array[z], num2Array[z], deno1Array[z], deno2Array[z]);
            System.out.printf("%1d/%1d   \t\t %1d/%1d\t\t %1d \t %1d", num1Array[z], deno1Array[z], num2Array[z], deno2Array[z], finalgcd, addFrac);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static int fracAdd(int num1, int num2, int deno1, int deno2)
    {
        int e = lcm(deno1, deno2); //denominator
        int f1 = e / deno1;
        int f2 = e / deno2;
        int g1 = num1 * f1;
        int g2 = num2 * f2;
        int adding = g1 + g2;
        int k = gcd(adding, e);
        int final_num = adding / k;
        int final_deno = e / k;
        if(final_num == final_deno){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return (final_num, final_deno);
        }
    }

    public static int gcd(int a, int b) //Calculate GCD
    {
        while (b > 0)
        {
            int temp = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = temp;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static int gcdfinal(int num1, int num2, int deno1, int deno2)
    {
        int e = lcm(deno1, deno2); //Calculate the GCD for display
        int f1 = e / deno1;
        int f2 = e / deno2;
        int g1 = num1 * f1;
        int g2 = num2 * f2;
        int end = g1 + g2;
        int k = gcd(end, e);
        return k;
    }
    public static int lcm(int a, int b) //Calculate LCM
    {
        return a * (b / gcd(a, b));
    }
}
```

How can I approach doing this? Am I on the right track?

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: You didn't show us the code for `gcdfinal()` and `fracAdd()`, which is where your problem (if any) lies.

Comment: Those are both methods at the bottom of the code

Comment: just a pointer for general use: when your loop variables don't have specific meaning like `row` or `column` or `table`, it is preferable (although of course not necessary) to use `i` as the loop variable. In nested loops, the procession is `i`, `j`, `k`, etc. What i'm saying is, all three of those loops could use `for(int x ...)` they don't have to be different variables.

Comment: I'm just not sure about how I can pass the added numerator and denominator to the table after the method. Also if it adds to 1 it has to only display 1.

Comment: And thank you Ben that is a good idea. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Also, integer arithmetic will round decimal values down to integers (e.g. 3 / 2 = 1).  You're probably introducing some error there.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, hopefully it helps you. :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddingFraction {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter a fraction number in a/b format: ");
    String fraction1 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("please enter another fraction number in a/b format: ");
    String fraction2 = sc.nextLine();
    addFractions(fraction1, fraction2);

}

public static void addFractions(String fractionNum1, String fractionNum2) {
    int numResult = 0;
    String resultFraction;
    String[] frcNum1 = fractionNum1.split("/");
    int numerator1 = Integer.parseInt(frcNum1[0]);
    int Denomenator1 = Integer.parseInt(frcNum1[1]);
    String[] frcNum2 = fractionNum2.split("/");
    int numerator2 = Integer.parseInt(frcNum2[0]);
    int Denomenator2 = Integer.parseInt(frcNum2[1]);
    if (Denomenator1 == Denomenator2) {
        numResult = numerator1 + numerator2;
        resultFraction = numResult + "/" + Denomenator1;
        System.out.println("Resultant Fraction is : "+resultFraction);
    } else {
        int denLcm = Denomenator1 * (Denomenator2 / gcd(Denomenator1, Denomenator2));;
        numResult = numerator1 * (denLcm / Denomenator1) + numerator2
                * (denLcm / Denomenator2);
        resultFraction = numResult + "/" + denLcm;
        System.out.println("Resultant Fraction is : "+resultFraction);
    }
}

private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (b > 0) {
        int temp = b;
        b = a % b; // % is remainder
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

}
```